# WebService Calling Problem

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, xml-serialization

I have Created a webService.

```
[WebMethod]    
        public void GetCommission(ArrayList Loc)
        {
        }
```

Now I am trying to call the Service I am getting the Xml Error. Please see the snapshot.
[image]

```
[XmlInclude(typeof(BOLibrary.Flight.DTContract))]
    [SoapInclude(typeof(BOLibrary.Flight.DTContract))]
    protected void btn_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ArrayList boArrayList = getList();
        Object[] obj = boArrayList.ToArray();  

        CommissionService service = new CommissionService();
        service.GetCommission(obj);
}
```

Please Help..

What is the solution of this..

[image]

Comment: It is hard to give an answer when you do not provide more details about the actual error. Try taking a look at the "InnerException" property of the exception.

Comment: @Ulrik: The InnerException is : {"The type BOLibrary.Flight.DTContract was not expected. Use the XmlInclude or SoapInclude attribute to specify types that are not known statically."}     I have used it but it still not working

Comment: @Florian : Ya sure...Please Help

Comment: Did any of the proposed solutions solve your problem, or are you still getting exceptions?

Answer (score 0):

You are putting the [XmlInclude] attribute in the wrong place. The problem is caused because you are serializing an object that is inherited from another object. Put the XmlInclude attribute on the base class of BOLibrary.Flight.DTContract.

Comment: You can check out the example here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlincludeattribute.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare the `XmlInclude` attribute on your service method.

```
[WebMethod]    
[XmlInclude(typeof(BOLibrary.Flight.DTContract))]
public void GetCommission(ArrayList Loc)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: @Florian: If i use [XmlInclude(typeof(BOLibrary.Flight.DTContract))] in Service Method...Now The DTContract get ambiguous because it getting the DTContract refrence from both service and DLL.

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand your problem. Do you get any compile errors or does it crash at runtime? In either case please provide error / exception message.

Comment: @Florian: Now, The Dtcommission from both ServiceNAmeSpace.DTContract and BOLibrary.Flight.DTContract. Please, See the Above Screenshot.

Comment: Try declaring a as BOLibrary.Flight.DTContract.

Comment: @Florian: Its not Working..We cant type cast the class in different name space

Comment: @Florian: Why webservice remove the name space from the DTContract class.